# Convert durations to a single unit

Tags: javascript, datetime

In the codebase I inherited, I have this function which converts a number and unit into milliseconds:

```js
function convertToMs(duration){
  const matcher = new RegExp(/-?(\d+)(ms|[smhd])/);
  const matches = matcher.exec(duration);

  const digit = Number(matches[1]);
  const suffix = matches[2];

  let milliSeconds = digit;

  switch(suffix) {
    case 'd': milliSeconds *= 24;
    case 'h': milliSeconds *= 60;
    case 'm': milliSeconds *= 60;
    case 's': milliSeconds *= 1000;
  }

  return milliSeconds;
}

console.log(`1s: ${convertToMs('1s')}`);
console.log(`3s: ${convertToMs('3s')}`);
console.log(`5m: ${convertToMs('5m')}`);
console.log(`1h: ${convertToMs('1h')}`);
console.log(`2d: ${convertToMs('2d')}`);
```

I'm especially concerned about the part that I thought was cool, but at the same time feels like it's using a side effect to achieve something; I am not sure if that's a good practice:

> ```
> switch(suffix) {
>    case 'd': milliSeconds *= 24;
>    case 'h': milliSeconds *= 60;
>    case 'm': milliSeconds *= 60;
>    case 's': milliSeconds *= 1000;
> }
> ```

Here, a number is being converted to milliseconds based on the suffix. The case rolls over into (all) the next case(s) to convert into milliseconds. Do you think that's okay?

Comment: I've edited to make this a valid review-request (on the understanding that this is code you are maintaining, as per site standard).

Comment: I would be more concerned about the assumption that one day is 24 hours. That is incorrect for all locations where DST is observed and you usually have two days each year with 23 and 25 hours.

Comment: @J_H `typeof convertToMs('1ms') => 'number'` - it's not returning a string.

Comment: @LocustHorde, quite right. I got hung up on the `milliSeconds = digit` assignment which I incorrectly read as grabbing the original input rather than grabbing a number. (Still don't know why we introduce that unfortunate `digit` identifier, which sometimes has e.g. "120" digits. Speaking of individual digits brought a connotation of string manipulation, and having told myself that fable I didn't even look backward a few lines to see if it was true. I was mostly focused on "we didn't multiply by `1` to ensure numeric", unlike the other return paths.) I thank you and I've withdrawn the remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address your specific concern, it's normal to highlight that fall-through to the next `case` is intentional, e.g. with a comment:

```
    case 'd': milliSeconds *= 24;   /* FALLTHROUGH */
    case 'h': milliSeconds *= 60;   /* FALLTHROUGH */
    case 'm': milliSeconds *= 60;   /* FALLTHROUGH */
    case 's': milliSeconds *= 1000;
```

The specific comment I've used is recognised by some compilers of related languages to silence a warning about *unintended* fall-through.

I'd consider adding `case 'ms': /* no action needed */'` to show explicitly that every match is handled.  And perhaps even a `default` so that if the regex is extended to support, say, "weeks", we're forced to handle that change rather than silently treating it the same as milliseconds.

---

Other problems in this function:

- `digit` is poorly named, since several digits may be matched.
- If the regular expression doesn't match, then `matches` won't have the values we're looking for - we need a reasonable error action here.
- Negative durations lose their `-` sign, becoming positive ones.  None of the test cases are negative, so this isn't caught.

Comment: A constant assignment is not worthy of fall through and as written does not structurally ensure order of execution (only via intentful english translation). Too easy to move a line up/down without syntax or runtime error.  -1 as there is no mention of the dangers or alternative. At the function tail a returned named constant is safer and more readable  `case DAY_SUFFIX: return digit * MILLI_SECONDS_PER_DAY; // and so on`

Comment: @Blindman67, that looks more like your own commentary on the code and worth converting to an answer.  I'd certainly give an upvote for that.